# Null Space versus Basis of a Null Space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling a lot with the terminology in linear algebra.

Would it be correct to say that if

$\operatorname{null}(A)=\operatorname{span} (\begin{bmatrix} -6 \\ -\frac{5}{2} \\ 1 \\0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -5 \\ -\frac{3}{2} \\ 0 \\1 \end{bmatrix})$

then

$\operatorname{basis}(\operatorname{null}(A))= \{\begin{bmatrix} -6 \\ -\frac{5}{2} \\ 1 \\0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -5 \\ -\frac{3}{2} \\ 0 \\1 \end{bmatrix}\}$ ?

Comment: Yes, because they are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you, Henno. Does this mean that I could define nul(A) using redundant vectors in the span? (And when I define the basis, the same two vectors would be used.)

Comment: Yes, there can be redundant vectors in the span, but for a base you have to find a *minimal* spanning set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be correct to say that it is *a* basis of the null space, but not that it is (as your notation hints) *the* basis (i.e. the only one) of the null space.